# How to get array in child component Angular?

Tags: angular

I am passing array to child component but it return empty array with zero length, but in parent it works fine.

Check below
[image]

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<app-schema-form [schema]="product_fields"></app-schema-form>
```

**TS**

```
export class SingleProductComponent implements OnInit {

  product_id: any;
  product_fields = [];

  constructor(...) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.product_id = ...;
    this.getProductFields();
  }

  getProductFields() {
    this.api.get('productfields', this.product_id).subscribe(res => {
      if (res[0]) {
        JSON.parse(res[0].product_fields).forEach(element => {
          this.product_fields.push(element);
        });
      }
      console.log(this.product_fields);
    })
  }
}
```

```
export class SchemaFormComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() schema: string[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.schema);
  }
}
```

Comment: could you post the HTML code?

Comment: See the updated code

Comment: Your console says that your child comp called before your parent. Hence the child is getting empty. How are loading your data in the parent? post what have you done so far.

Comment: @RobinSingh Can you post all relevant code. You haven't shown how `product_fields` is set, and where the other `console.log` is

Comment: Don't initialize to blank array , Simply use @Input() schema: string ; or use different hooks such as onChange

Comment: @smart74 see updated post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're logging the child values in the `ngOnInit` of the child. The parent will pass the value after your service has returned its value. Your service will certainly return the value after the child's `ngOnInit` has been called.

To ensure you run code after the child value has been received, use `ngOnChanges()`.

[The docs](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) for `ngOnChanges` states that it is:

> A callback method that is invoked immediately after the default change detector has checked data-bound properties if at least one has changed, and before the view and content children are checked.

```js
export class SchemaFormComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() schema: string[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.schema) {
      console.log(this.schema);
    }
  }
}
```

Another issue you are having is that you are initialising your `product_fields` array as empty. This means that when you push new values to your array, `ngOnChanges()` doesn't get run as it is *still the same object*. Instead, leave your array as undefined and only set it once you have the data. This will trigger `ngOnChanges` in the child once it is set.

```js
export class SingleProductComponent implements OnInit {

  product_id: any;
  product_fields: []; // <--- declare undefined array

  constructor(...) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.product_id = ...;
    this.getProductFields();
  }

  getProductFields() {
    this.api.get('productfields', this.product_id).subscribe(res => {
      if (res[0]) {
        // assign array here
        this.product_fields = JSON.parse(res[0].product_fields); 
      }
      console.log(this.product_fields);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Again same response

Answer (score 0):

#### Parent

```
export class SingleProductComponent implements OnInit {

  product_id: any;
  product_fields: any[];

  constructor(...) { }

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.product_id = ...;
    await this.getProductFields();
  }

   async getProductFields() {
      const response = await this.api.get('productfields', this.product_id).toPromise();
      if (response[0]) {
         this.product_fields = JSON.parse(response[0].product_fields);
      }
      console.log(this.product_fields);
  }
```

#### HTML

```
<app-schema-form [schema]="product_fields"></app-schema-form>
```

#### Child

```
export class SchemaFormComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  private _schema: string[];
  public get schema(): string[] {
    return this._schema;
  }

  @Input()
  public set schema(value: string[]) {
    this._schema = value;
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
     if (changes.schema) {
        console.log(this.schema);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: You've not explained what you've done and why it would work. Why have you switched to using a promise? The problem is fixed by checking `ngOnChanges` and not declaring an empty array. Converting it to a promise is an unecessary extra step.

Comment: @KurtHamilton, that's my way of writing clean code, instead of subscribers. BTW, I upvoted your answer as I liked your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In order to trigger angular's life cycle you need to create a change of reference.
When you use

```
JSON.parse(res[0].product_fields).forEach(element => {
    this.product_fields.push(element);
});
```

you push elements to an existing array.
In order to change the reference of the array all you need to do is

```
this.product_fields = [...res[0].product_fields]
```

Now, since you get the products in an async way, you cannot assume that the data is there on init.
I'd do the following:

```
export class SchemaFormComponent {
    private _schema: string[];
    @Input() set schema(_schema: string[]) {
        console.log('_schema: ', _schema);
        this._schema = _schema;
    }

    get schema(): string[] {
        return this._schema;
    }

    constructor() { }
}
```

Hope this helps!